# Meta analysis using the effect size based on mean and multiple outcomes

Tags: meta-analysis

I have few questions on the meta analysis. 
First, the data is longitudinal and according to the CMA (comprehensive meta analysis) guidebook
"Working with more than two outcomes per study
The formulas presented for a difference based on two outcomes can be extended to
accommodate any number of outcomes using contrasts."
My concern is how to choose proper contrast.
The data shape is in a way that intervention shows better results for earlier time but both intervention and control have bouncing back effect and eventually get to similar results over time.
So my first trial for the contrast was using same weight.
For example, contrast 1 = T0-0.5T1-0.5T2
conrast 2 = T0-1/3T1-1/3T2-1/3T3 and so on. (Different studies have different time points).
In this way I noticed that the equal weight contrast results in not significant differences.
Would it be valid if I put more weight into earlier time points (T1,T2) and less weights to later time points (T3 and on)?

Comment: I think you pick the contrast that matches the question you want to ask. When you are talking about time, these are different analyses - so you need to pick a time, and a contrast.

Comment: @JeremyMiles I think I'm confused a bit. Say Y_ij denote for mean response of ith study and jth time. Then my understanding is that the contrast will be something like Y_11 - 0.5*Y_12-0.5*Y_13. I did that based on my understanding of the CMA material (https://www.meta-analysis.com/downloads/Meta-analysis%20Studies%20with%20multiple%20subgroups%20or%20outcomes.pdf). They use the Y_11-Y_12 and SD(Y_11-Y_12) and use it on the analysis. 
Are you telling me that I need to pick a time and conduct meta analysis on all studies based on that time?

Comment: I've always picked a time - or multiple times, but there might be better ways to do it. I'm not familiar with the CMA material.

Comment: Can you clarify how the situation differs from the one you asked about previously http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253657/methods-of-meta-analysis here?